# Adobe Air - Opening a File With Air

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air

So I've created an Air app that saves to a custom file type. I've set up the file associations when I publish the app and, when you double click the file it opens the air app. What are the hooks for me to detect that the app has been opened via a file? Obviously, I need to detect this and then get the app to open the file itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen to the [InvokeEvent](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/InvokeEvent.html) which will hold into the `arguments` property the file name requested:

Quick mxml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    xmlns:s="spark.components.*"
    invoke="onAppInvoke(event);">
    <mx:Script><![CDATA[
      import mx.controls.Alert;

      private function onAppInvoke(event:InvokeEvent):void {
        if (event.arguments.length>0) {
           // ok app call with an arguments
           var fileName:String=event.arguments[0];
           Alert.show("app open with : "+fileName);
        } else {
           // app open normally
           Alert.show("normal launch");
        }
      }
     ]]></mx:Script>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 5):

Listen for the `invoke` event on the [WindowedApplication](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/WindowedApplication.html#event:invoke) or its [nativeApplication](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html#event:invoke). It has an [arguments](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/events/InvokeEvent.html#arguments) array property that holds the string arguments passed during this invocation.

> The `NativeApplication` object of an AIR application dispatches an `invoke` event when the application is invoked.
>
> The `NativeApplication` object always dispatches an invoke event when an application is launched, but the event may be dispatched at other times as well. For example, a running application dispatches an additional `InvokeEvent` when a user activates a file associated with the application.
>
> Only a single instance of a particular application can be launched. Subsequent attempts to launch the application will result in a new invoke event dispatched by the `NativeApplication` object of the running instance. It is an application's responsibility to handle this event and take the appropriate action, such as opening a new application window to display the data in a file.
>
> `InvokeEvent` objects are dispatched by the `NativeApplication` object (`NativeApplication.nativeApplication`). To receive invoke  events, call the `addEventListener()` method of the `NativeApplication` object. When an event listener registers for an invoke event, it will also receive all `invoke` events that occurred before the registration. These earlier events are dispatched after the call to `addEventListener()` returns, but not necessarily before a new invoke event that might be might be dispatched after registration. Thus, you should not rely on dispatch order.

```
<mx:WindowedApplication creationComplete="init()">
  <mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
     public function init():void
     {
          NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.Invoke, onInvoke);
     }
     public function onInvoke(e:InvokeEvent):void
     {
          var args:Array = e.arguments;
          trace("There are " + args.length + " arguments");
          for(var i:int = 0; i < args.length; i++)
          {
               trace("Argument #" + i + " " + args[i]);
          }
     }
  ]]>
  </mx:Script>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```